# Criar layout com `content` responsivo

Tags: html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um layout, mas preciso de ajuda.

Eu quero criar um `content` que se adeque à página.

[código de exemplo.](https://jsfiddle.net/zutbwk2a/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <title>Start Template</title>

</head>

<body class="theme-teal">
    <nav class="navbar"></nav>
 <aside id="leftsidebar" class="sidebar main-sidebar">
     <div class="legal">
            <div class="copyright">© copyright 2019</div>
        </div>
 </aside>
 
 <section class="content">
     <div class="main-content">
            <p id="">CONTENT</p>
  </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
<style>
    .navbar {
     border-radius: 0;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 .theme-teal .navbar {
        background-color: #009688;
    }
 .sidebar {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 11 !important;
 }
 .theme-teal .sidebar .legal {
     background-color: #fff;
 }
 .sidebar .legal {
     position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .content {
     min-height: 250px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
 }
 .mainNav {
     margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: #ecf0f5;
 }
 
 @media (max-width: 1187px){
     .sidebar {
         width: 0px;
     }
 } 
 
</style>
```

Quero que dentro deste `content`, seja exibido toda informação da página.

**OBSERVAÇÃO**
O `content` permanece visível na tela, conforme marcação da imagem abaixo, e as informações dentro dele, pode correr num `scroll`, se necessário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem que ajustar muitas propriedades no CSS para posicionar a `section`. Veja que utilizei alguns `calc()` no `width` (descontando a largura da sidebar) e `height` (ajustando à altura da tela), coloquei à direita com `float`, coloquei um `margin-top` da altura do `nav` para que a `section` não fique por baixo, ajustei a largura da classe `.legal` descontando os `paddings`, entre outros vários ajustes. Se for comentar um por um vai ficar enorme a resposta. O melhor é você ver as diferenças no CSS e comparar com seu código original.

> É importante também resetar a margem do `body` com `margin: 0`. Além
>   de tirar o overflow e colocar apenas na `section`, como você
>   explicitou na pergunta.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <title>Start Template</title>

</head>

<body class="theme-teal">
    <nav class="navbar"></nav>
 <aside id="leftsidebar" class="sidebar main-sidebar">
     <div class="legal">
            <div class="copyright">© copyright 2019</div>
        </div>
 </aside>
 
 <section class="content">
     <div class="main-content">
            <p id="">CONTENT</p>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>



            
  </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
<style>
body{
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden; 
}
    .navbar {
     border-radius: 0;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 .theme-teal .navbar {
        background-color: #009688;
    }
 .sidebar {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 11 !important;
 }
 .theme-teal .sidebar .legal {
     background-color: #fff;
 }
 .sidebar .legal {
     position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 270px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .content {
      float: right;
      width: calc(100vw - 330px);
     height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  padding: 15px;
      margin-top: 50px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
 }
   
   .main-content{
      background: #FFEECF;
      padding: 15px;
      height: calc(100vh - 110px);
      overflow: auto;
   }
 .mainNav {
     margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: #ecf0f5;
 }
 
 @media (max-width: 1187px){
     .sidebar {
         width: 0px;
     }
 } 
 
</style>
```

Comment: na imagem, para a classe `main-content` eu alterei a cor do fundo e adicionei um shadow, para explicar melhor..
Eu quero que o `content` seja fixo na página e se adeque a resulução da tela, porém seja sempre visível da forma que está na imagem, o único conteúdo que vai mudar, será o que está dentro de `main-content`.. É possível ? https://i.imgur.com/hGl7yGQg.png

Comment: Veja agora.....

Comment: Muito bom, agradeço pelo tempo, resposta e ajuda..