# Aplicar responsividade

Tags: css, layout-responsivo

[image: tela estendida]

Como podemos ver na primeira imagem com a telá estendida está certo porem quando eu redimensiono a tela as tabelas saem da organização, podem me ajudar a manter as tabelas redimensionando de acordo com o tamanho da tela?

[image: Problema ao minimizar tela]

```
{
html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100px;
}



body {
    font-family: "Verdana",Times,serif;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    height: 55em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    font-size: 15px;
}

textarea {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    font-family: "Verdana", Times, serif;
    font-size: 100px;
}

img {
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 7px;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 3.8%;
}


.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 4.5em;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    margin: auto;
}


.menu {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(00, 87, 147);
    height: 2.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    color: #d5d1d1;
}

#usuario {
    line-height: 3.5em;
    margin-right: 7em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.menu ul {
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 6.3%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: left;
}

    .menu ul li {
        display: inline-flex;
        color: white;
    }

        .menu ul li a {
            padding: 8px 20px;
            color: #d5d1d1;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            .menu ul li a:hover {
                color: #fff;
                background: #4698ca;
                border-top-color: #5db1e0 !important;
                border-left-color: #5db1e0;
            }



.content {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}


.content2 {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 1em auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}


.footer {
    width: 98%;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 13%;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #333333;
}

.button {
    background-color: rgb(00, 87, 147);
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 173px;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: rgb(00, 87, 147);
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 237px;
}

#buttonConsulta {
    background-color: rgb(00, 87, 147);
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 237px;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

    #buttonConsulta:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background: #4698ca;
        border-top-color: #5db1e0 !important;
        border-left-color: #5db1e0;
    }

.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #4698ca;
    border-top-color: #5db1e0 !important;
    border-left-color: #5db1e0;
}

.button2:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #4698ca;
    border-top-color: #5db1e0 !important;
    border-left-color: #5db1e0;
}

.campos-texto {
    border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    width: 165px;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-family: tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.campos-texto2 {
    border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    width: 230px;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-family: tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.editor-label {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.form {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    float: left;
}

.form2 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

p {
    font-family: "Verdana", Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.conteudo {
    height: 47%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 9%;
    background: red;
}

.configuracoes {
    margin-left: 70px;
    font-size: small;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

.form fieldset {
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
```

}

me descupem a ignorância, peço ajuda e desde já agradeço.

aqui o restante do codigo:

```
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPageHome.cshtml";

var grid1 = new WebGrid(Model.inciAnalista, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 7, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent2");
var grid2 = new WebGrid(Model.gmudAnalista, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 7, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent2");
var grid3 = new WebGrid(Model.demandaAnalista, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 7, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent2");
var grid4 = new WebGrid(Model.problemaAnalista, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 7, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent2");
var grid5 = new WebGrid(Model.totalAnalista, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 7, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent2");
var grid6 = new WebGrid(Model.totalAnalista, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 7, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent2");
var grid7 = new WebGrid(Model.totalAnalista, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 7, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent2");

int r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;
r1 = Model.totalAnalista[0].umMes;
r2 = Model.totalAnalista[0].duasSemanas;
r3 = Model.totalAnalista[0].noPrazo;
r4 = Model.totalAnalista[0].planejada;
r5 = Model.totalAnalista[0].incidente;

e1 = Model.totalAnalista[1].umMes;
e2 = Model.totalAnalista[1].duasSemanas;
e3 = Model.totalAnalista[1].noPrazo;
e4 = Model.totalAnalista[1].planejada;
e5 = Model.totalAnalista[1].incidente;

a1 = Model.totalAnalista[2].umMes;
a2 = Model.totalAnalista[2].duasSemanas;
a3 = Model.totalAnalista[2].noPrazo;
a4 = Model.totalAnalista[2].planejada;
a5 = Model.totalAnalista[2].incidente;

h1 = Model.totalAnalista[3].umMes;
h2 = Model.totalAnalista[3].duasSemanas;
h3 = Model.totalAnalista[3].noPrazo;
h4 = Model.totalAnalista[3].planejada;
h5 = Model.totalAnalista[3].incidente;

f1 = Model.totalAnalista[4].umMes;
f2 = Model.totalAnalista[4].duasSemanas;
f3 = Model.totalAnalista[4].noPrazo;
f4 = Model.totalAnalista[4].planejada;
f5 = Model.totalAnalista[4].incidente;


l1 = Model.totalAnalista[5].umMes;
l2 = Model.totalAnalista[5].duasSemanas;
l3 = Model.totalAnalista[5].noPrazo;
l4 = Model.totalAnalista[5].planejada;
l5 = Model.totalAnalista[5].incidente;

c1 = Model.totalAnalista[6].umMes;
c2 = Model.totalAnalista[6].duasSemanas;
c3 = Model.totalAnalista[6].noPrazo;
c4 = Model.totalAnalista[6].planejada;
c5 = Model.totalAnalista[6].incidente;
}
```

o restante:

```
{
(document).ready(function () { $("#gridContent tbody tr").each(function (i, row) { var $actualRow = $(row); if ($actualRow.find('td').eq(3).text() > 0 && $actualRow.find('td').eq(4).text() 0 && $actualRow.find('td').eq(3).text()



    .webGrid {
        margin: 20px;
        margin-left: 110px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 40%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 13px;
        float: left;
    }

    .webGrid2 {
        margin: 10px;
        margin-left: 990px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 30%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    .headerGrid a {
        color: rgb(00, 87, 147);
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .comentario {
        max-width: 200px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .grafico {
        float: right;
    }

    #chartContainer,
    #chartContainer2 {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }

    #chartContainer3,
    #chartContainer4 {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }

    #chartContainer5 {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }

    #chartContainer6,
    #chartContainer7 {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }

    @*@foreach (var item in Model.totalAnalista) {}

    *@ @grid1.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", headerStyle: "headerGrid", alternatingRowStyle: "alt", selectedRowStyle: "select", columns: grid1.Columns( grid1.Column("analista", " Analista"), grid1.Column("incidente", "Incidentes"), grid1.Column("noPrazo", "No Prazo"), grid1.Column("duasSemanas", "Mais De 2 Semanas"), grid1.Column("umMes", "Mais De 1 Mês"), grid1.Column("planejada", "Planejada"))) @grid2.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", headerStyle: "headerGrid", alternatingRowStyle: "alt", selectedRowStyle: "select", columns: grid2.Columns( grid2.Column("analista", " Analista"), grid2.Column("incidente", "G.M.U.Ds."), grid2.Column("noPrazo", "No Prazo"), grid2.Column("duasSemanas", "Mais De 2 Semanas"), grid2.Column("umMes", "Mais De 1 Mês"), grid2.Column("Planejada"))) @grid3.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", headerStyle: "headerGrid", alternatingRowStyle: "alt", selectedRowStyle: "select", columns: grid3.Columns( grid3.Column("analista", " Analista"), grid3.Column("incidente", "Demandas"), grid3.Column("noPrazo", "No Prazo"), grid3.Column("duasSemanas", "Mais De 2 Semanas"), grid3.Column("umMes", "Mais De 1 Mês"), grid3.Column("planejada", "Planejada"))) @grid4.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", headerStyle: "headerGrid", alternatingRowStyle: "alt", selectedRowStyle: "select", columns: grid4.Columns( grid4.Column("analista", " Analista"), grid4.Column("incidente", "Problemas"), grid4.Column("noPrazo", "No Prazo"), grid4.Column("duasSemanas", "Mais De 2 Semanas"), grid4.Column("umMes", "Mais De 1 Mês"), grid4.Column("planejada", "Planejada"))) @grid5.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid2", headerStyle: "headerGrid", alternatingRowStyle: "alt", selectedRowStyle: "select", columns: grid5.Columns( grid5.Column("analista", " Analista"), grid5.Column("incidente", "Totalidade"), grid5.Column("noPrazo", "No Prazo"), grid5.Column("duasSemanas", "Mais De 2 Semanas"), grid5.Column("umMes", "Mais De 1 Mês"), grid5.Column("planejada", "Planejada"))) var randomScalingFactor=function () {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    }

    ;
    var config= {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [ {
                data: [ @r1, @r2, @r3, @r4 ], backgroundColor: [ "#de4e3a", window.chartColors.yellow, window.chartColors.blue, window.chartColors.green, ], label: "Romulo Cano"
            }
            ],
            labels: [ "1 Mês +",
            "2 Semanas +",
            "No Prazo",
            "Planejada"],
        }
        ,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true, text: 'Romulo Cano Total: '+@r5
            }
        }
    }

    ;
    var config2= {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [ {
                data: [ @e1, @e2, @e3, @e4 ], backgroundColor: [ "#de4e3a", window.chartColors.yellow, window.chartColors.blue, window.chartColors.green, ], label: 'Dataset 1'
            }
            ],
            labels: [ "1 Mês +",
            "2 Semanas +",
            "No Prazo",
            "Planejada"]
        }
        ,
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
        ,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true, text: 'Ericles Silva Total: '+@e5
            }
        }
    }

    ;
    var config3= {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [ {
                data: [ @a1, @a2, @a3, @a4 ], backgroundColor: [ "#de4e3a", window.chartColors.yellow, window.chartColors.blue, window.chartColors.green, ], label: 'Dataset 1'
            }
            ],
            labels: [ "1 Mês +",
            "2 Semanas +",
            "No Prazo",
            "Planejada",
            ]
        }
        ,
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
        ,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true, text: 'Anderson Litri Total: '+@a5
            }
        }
    }

    ;
    var config4= {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [ {
                data: [ @h1, @h2, @h3, @h4 ], backgroundColor: [ "#de4e3a", window.chartColors.yellow, window.chartColors.blue, window.chartColors.green, ], label: 'Dataset 1'
            }
            ],
            labels: [ "1 Mês +",
            "2 Semanas +",
            "No Prazo",
            "Planejada"]
        }
        ,
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
        ,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true, text: 'Henrique Giopato Total: '+@h5
            }
        }
    }

    ;
    var config5= {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [ {
                data: [ @f1, @f2, @f3, @f4 ], backgroundColor: [ "#e13f3a", window.chartColors.yellow, window.chartColors.blue, window.chartColors.green, ], label: 'Dataset 1'
            }
            ],
            labels: [ "1 Mês +",
            "2 Semanas +",
            "No Prazo",
            "Planejada"]
        }
        ,
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
        ,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true, text: 'Francisco Melo Total: '+@f5
            }
        }
    }

    ;
    var config6= {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [ {
                data: [ @l1, @l2, @l3, @l4 ], backgroundColor: [ "#e13f3a", window.chartColors.yellow, window.chartColors.blue, window.chartColors.green, ], label: 'Dataset 1'
            }
            ],
            labels: [ "1 Mês +",
            "2 Semanas +",
            "No Prazo",
            "Planejada"]
        }
        ,
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
        ,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true, text: 'Lucas Silva Total: ' +@l5
            }
        }
    }

    ;
    var config7= {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [ {
                data: [ @c1, @c2, @c3, @c4 ], backgroundColor: [ "#e13f3a", window.chartColors.yellow, window.chartColors.blue, window.chartColors.green, ], label: 'Dataset 1'
            }
            ],
            labels: [ "1 Mês +",
            "2 Semanas +",
            "No Prazo",
            "Planejada"]
        }
        ,
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
        ,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true, text: 'Caroline Muniz Total: '+@c5
            }
        }
    }

    ;
    window.onload=function () {
        var ctx=document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie=new Chart(ctx, config);
        var ctx2=document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie=new Chart(ctx2, config2);
        var ctx3=document.getElementById("chart-area3").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie=new Chart(ctx3, config3);
        var ctx4=document.getElementById("chart-area4").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie=new Chart(ctx4, config4);
        var ctx5=document.getElementById("chart-area5").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie=new Chart(ctx5, config5);
        var ctx6=document.getElementById("chart-area6").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie=new Chart(ctx6, config6);
        var ctx7=document.getElementById("chart-area7").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie=new Chart(ctx7, config7);
    }

    ;

    }

}
```

Comment: E o HTML cade??

Comment: Desculpe, postei o restante agora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta usar:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Você pode dá uma olhada mais aprofundada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383840/79242

Comment: Bom dia @EvertonGouveia, ja tinha feito isto antes e não deu resultado, quando a tela é redimensionada as tabelas continuam ficando desordenadas,vou continuar pesquisando pra achar uma solução mas obrigado

Comment: Você pode tentar também repassar para o bootstrap, possa ser que te ajude também..